# geoNear mongodb always returns empty results

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I used geoNear mongodb method to query the closest restaurant listing against my sample data sets.

When I query for the closest restaurant result I get empty results even if I have available data.

Here is my query data

```
   db.runCommand(
   {
     geoNear: "restaurantCollection",
     near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -84.369605, 33.822451 ] },
     spherical: true,
     query: { cusine: "Thai" },
     minDistance: 0,
     maxDistance: 10000
   }
)
```

Here is my sample json restaurant listing data based on geo coordinates.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "1",
        "name": "Ameer's Mediterranean Grill",
        "cuisine": "Halal, Mediterranean, Middle Eastern",
        "iconPath": "Ameers-Mediterranean.png",
        "contact": {
            "phone": "4049820666",
            "formattedPhone": "(404)982-0666",
            "twitter": "",
            "email": "",
            "faxNumber": ""
        },
        "address": {
            "street": "2168 Briarcliff Rd NE",
            "crossStreet": "2168 Briarcliff Rd NE",
            "city": "Atlanta",
            "state": "GA",
            "zipcode": "30329",
            "country": "usa",
            "formattedAddress": [
                "2168 Briarcliff Rd NE",
                "Atlanta, GA, 30329",
                "United States"
            ],  
            "lat": "33.816845",
            "lng": "-84.335677",
            "location": { 
                  "type " : "Point",
                   "coordinates" :[-84.335677, 33.816845]
            }
        },
        "rating": "",
        "hours": "11:00AM - 9:30PM"
    },
    {
        "_id":"2",
        "name": "26 Thai Kitchen & Bar",
        "cuisine": "Thai",
        "iconPath": "26ThaiKitchenBar_541_Atlanta_GA.png",
        "contact": {
            "phone": "4044005995",
            "formattedPhone": " (404) 400-5995",
            "twitter": "",
            "email": "",
            "faxNumber": ""
        },
        "address": {
            "street": "541 Main St NE",
            "crossStreet": "541 Main St NE",
            "city": "Atlanta",
            "state": "GA",
            "zipcode": "30324",
            "country": "usa",
            "formattedAddress": [
                "541 Main St NE",
                "Atlanta, GA, 30324",
                "United States"
            ],
            "lat": "33.822451",
            "lng": "-84.369605",
            "location": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates":[-84.369605, 33.822451]
            }
        },
        "rating": "",
        "hours": "3:00PM - 9:15PM"
    },
    {
        "_id": "3",
        "name": "Cabo Cantina Atlanta",
        "cuisine": "Latin American, Spanish, Tacos",
        "iconPath": "CaboCantinaAtlanta.png",
        "contact": {
            "phone": "4049172620",
            "formattedPhone": "(404) 917-2620",
            "twitter": "",
            "email": "",
            "faxNumber": ""
        },
        "address": {
            "street": "264 Pharr Road Northeast",
            "crossStreet": "264 Pharr Road Northeast",
            "city": "Atlanta",
            "state": "GA",
            "zipcode": "30305",
            "country": "usa",
            "formattedAddress": [
                "264 Pharr Road Northeast",
                "Atlanta, GA, 30305",
                "United States"
            ],
            "lat": "33.837200",
            "lng": "-84.378011",
            "location": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates":[-84.378011, 33.837200]
            }
        },
        "rating": "",
        "hours": "11:30AM - 9:00PM"
    }]
```

I would appreciate if some can help me resolving the issue.  Here is what I see on my mongo shell.

```
"waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
"results" : [ ],
"stats" : {
    "nscanned" : 0,
    "objectsLoaded" : 0,
    "maxDistance" : 0,
    "time" : 0
},
"ok" : 1
```

Comment: I noticed a typo on your query `query: { cusine: "Thai" }` - Cuisine missing an `i`. Is this just a typo when you post the question  ? Cheers.

Comment: Fixed the typo, but still haven't resolved it yet.

Answer (score 0):

The [geoNear command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/geoNear/) requires that a collection have at most only one 2dsphere and/or only one [2d index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2d/). Based on your example, please see [2dsphere index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/) to create an index for the collection.

For example:

```
db.restaurantCollection.createIndex({"address.location":"2dsphere"})
```

Worth mentioning that [Views](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/) (available in MongoDB v3.4+) do no support geoNear operations.